# Can't have a term and geo_distance_range in the same must filter

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have some data and I am trying to get all the results that have a certain month and are less than 1.6km from the target point. I am using the PHP client so my query looks like this.

```
$crimeSearch = [
            'size' => 0,
            'query' => [
                'filtered' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => [
                                'term' => [
                                    'month' => $date,
                                ],
                                'geo_distance_range' => [
                                    'location' => [
                                        'lat' => $lat,
                                        'lon' => $lng,
                                    ],
                                    'lt' => '1.6km',
                                ],

                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'aggs' => [
                'group_by_category' => [
                    'terms' => [
                        'field' => 'category',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
```

I am currently seeing the following error:

```
query_parsing_exception: No query registered for [location]
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
"properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "category": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "month": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
```

Now if I comment out either the term value or the geo_distance_range value from the must array then I get the correct results back. This error only occurs when they are both present.

Can anyone see what I wrong with my query?

I have tried moving the geo_distance_range into its own must block but this seems to bring back all results that match either of the the must filters and not them both.

If you need any more information please ask!

Thank you.

Comment: What version of ES you are using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.0. This is solved now. I just has to wrap each of my must filters in their own array. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know anything about PHP but If I try to convert equivalent `ES json query` then this might work. I guess you need to put every `must clause` in array like this

```
[
    'size' => 0,
    'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            'filter' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'month' => $date,
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'geo_distance_range' => [
                                'location' => [
                                    'lat' => $lat,
                                    'lon' => $lng,
                                ],
                                'lt' => '1.6km',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'aggs' => [
        'group_by_category' => [
            'terms' => [
                'field' => 'category',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

This is equivalent to

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "month": "June"
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance_range": {
                "lt": "1.6km",
                "location": {
                  "lat": 37.9174,
                  "lon": -122.305
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does this work?